# How to get alternate rows in dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Using data set `mtcars`, I'm not able to find f)Load `mtcars` data frame into R console and retrieve the following data from the data table

- a) Get the headers, dimensions and structure of `mtcars` data frame
- b) Get first 15 rows and 15 columns
- c) Get first column of first 20 rows
- d) Get second column of first 20 rows
- e) Get only second column
- f) Get only alternate rows and all its corresponding columns

Comment: Please read [How do I ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: head(mtcars)
dim(mtcars)
str(mtcars)
mtcars[1:15,]
mtcars[,1:11]
as.data.frame(mtcars[1:20,1])
as.data.frame(mtcars[2:20,2])
as.data.frame(mtcars[,2])

Comment: @student45 Edit your question. [Learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) how to format your question properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question looks very weird to me. you can use the following codes:

```
colnames(mtcars)
 [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
> dim(mtcars)
[1] 32 11
> str(mtcars)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...


mtcars[1:15,1:6]
                    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt
Mazda RX4          21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620
Mazda RX4 Wag      21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875
Datsun 710         22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320
Hornet 4 Drive     21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215
Hornet Sportabout  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440
Valiant            18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460
Duster 360         14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570
Merc 240D          24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190
Merc 230           22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150
Merc 280           19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440
Merc 280C          17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440
Merc 450SE         16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070
Merc 450SL         17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730
Merc 450SLC        15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780
Cadillac Fleetwood 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250


mtcars[1:20,1]
 [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9

 mtcars[1:20,2]
 [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4


 mtcars[,2]
 [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4




mtcars <- mutate(mtcars, name=row.names(mtcars))
> mtcars$ID <- seq(nrow(mtcars))
> mtcars[mtcars$ID %% 2 ==1,]
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb               name ID
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4          Mazda RX4  1
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1         Datsun 710  3
5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2  Hornet Sportabout  5
7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4         Duster 360  7
9  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2           Merc 230  9
11 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4          Merc 280C 11
13 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3         Merc 450SL 13
15 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4 Cadillac Fleetwood 15
17 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4  Chrysler Imperial 17
19 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2        Honda Civic 19
21 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1      Toyota Corona 21
23 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2        AMC Javelin 23
25 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2   Pontiac Firebird 25
27 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2      Porsche 914-2 27
29 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4     Ford Pantera L 29
31 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8      Maserati Bora 31
```

Comment: how to get alternate rows from this

Comment: could you explain more what you want? what is your expectation?

Comment: i want to display my rows as 1,3,5,7,9,.. ie first item in 1st row then third element in 3rd row and then fifth elemnent in 5th and vice versa and show the corresponding columns

Comment: the rows should be like Mazda RX4,Datsun,Hornet Sportabout,Duster360........

Comment: I have added some codes you look at.